# Using MPI with a .sh script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, c++, mpi

I have a `runPR.sh` script as below

```
DIR=/directory/buildagain/bin/Project
 FILELIST=$1

 while read FILE
 do
     echo "Processing ${FILE}..."
     ./makeInp.sh ${FILE} ${FILE} >INP/${FILE}.inp
     ${DIR} -PR INP/${FILE}.inp
 done < ${FILELIST}
```

For the serial program, I run the program by typing `make` in `/directory/buildagain` and then `./runPR.sh values.txt`. (`values.txt` just contains the line `Chain`)

EDIT:
Here is a small portion of my code.

```
 int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] )
 {
      MPI_Status status;
      MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); 
      if( strcmp(argv[1],"-PR") == 0 )
           runPR(argc-2, &argv[2]);
      return 0;
 }

 int runPR(int argc, char* argv[])
 { 
      cout<<"run here"<<endl;

      int mynode, totalnodes;
      int sum,startval,endval,accum;
      int master=0;

      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &totalnodes); // get totalnodes
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mynode); // get mynode

      PROpt opt;
      Solve* ps = new Solve();
      cout<<"here1"<<endl;

      cout<<"total nodes "<<totalnodes<<endl;
      for(int j=0;j<totalnodes-1;j=j+1){

           cout<<"processor"<<mynode<<"  received from "<<j<<endl;

           ps->getFile(&opt,argv[0]);
      }
 }
```

By typing `mpirun -np 4 ../directory/buildagain/bin/Project -PR INP/Chain.inp`, I see `run here`, `here`, `total nodes1` printed 4 times. But I don't see `cout<<"processor"<<mynode<<"  received from "<<j<<endl;` printed out, and I would expected `total nodes` to show 4, not 1. Also, the program just stops. Why is this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that mpirun needs an actual executable that is linked against the MPI library. A shell script won't work. Which implementation and version of MPI are you running?

Can you show me your line of code with ``mpi_init`` please?

Comment: The executable is at /directory/buildagain/bin/Project. The `runPR.sh` calls the executable there. I am using openmpi/1.6

Comment: I made some changes to the OP in that I posted a small code sample.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with gcc 5.1 and OpenMPI 1.8.4.  I get the expected behavior based on your code example.  How many CPU cores do you have?  Can you compile and run simple MPI programs as expected?  I won't address the issues with your code logic as that is  offtopic for this site.

Comment: I'm using gcc/4.7 and openmpi/1.6. Again, I have no problems with a helloworld program and an MWE of my actual code. However, my actual code shows only 1 node for `cout<<"This node="<<mynode<<endl;`

Answer (score 1):

After you reported getting output like

```
total nodes=1
```

and

```
This node=0
```

printed out 4 times, I concluded you are trying this: `mpirun -np 4 script-name.sh`. It does this because mpirun is launching 4 copies of a shell script which doesn't understand MPI communication semantics.

If you *can* somehow get launch mpirun on a script, then remember (1) the script is running in the local "head" node environment, not the remote one, (2) the script must `exec` to your program as its last and final breath, and (3) when the program runs, it's in the environment on possibly another node -- possibly not having access to the files you had on the head.

So the script should look like this:

```
PROG="$1"; shift;
OPT="$2"; shift    
for FILE in "$@"
do
     echo "Processing ${FILE}..."
     ./makeInp.sh ${FILE} ${FILE} >INP/${FILE}.inp
done
exec $PROG $OPT "$@"
```

Within `PROG`, you'll have to index `ARGV` to correspond to the current node/thread. (Do check that you haven't exceeded `argc` or you'll get a NULL-pointer violation.) I don't think there's another/better way.

Comment: typing `mpirun -np 4 ../directory/buildagain/bin/Project -PR INP/Chain.inp` with your changes to the script, I get the same output as before

Comment: So without the script at all? That's not good. Too much is dependent on your environemnt. Did you tell me at one point that `mpirun -np 4 helloworld` actually ran 4 threads? If not, maybe your system simply isn't configured for more than one node. (Even then, it would invoke 4 instances on one node...) I'm stumped.

Comment: Also, I noticed a problem with the modified script. I edited the answer to reflect.

Comment: typing `mpirun -np 4 ../directory/buildagain/bin/Project -PR INP/Chain.inp` with the modified script, I noticed no new changes. When I type `mpirun -np 4 ./runPR.sh values.txt`,I still get the `mpirun aborted` message

Comment: yes, `mpirun -np 4 helloworld` shows the 4 difference processors

Comment: Wait, in the 1st case, you're not even running the shell script. In the 2nd case, it's clear that mpirun won't allow you to launch a shell script (which is what i sort of thought to begin with. Last time I used mpi, btw, it was 1.1 or something).

Comment: remove from your code the `Solve.new` and `getFile` code. Keep removing code until it is nearly identical to `helloworld`. Eventually you'll see the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Something is wrong with his other code or his environment. I couldn't repro his code reduced to a mvce (taking out calls he didn't provide code for).

Comment: To OP: Could it be your execution path/executable is not available on all nodes/hosts where mpirun starts execution? (Or is everything actually local on the same computer node/host?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How can I check if the executable is available on all nodes when mpirun starts? I am using the multiple nodes on the same machine. Also, I was able to get the helloworld example on the PETSc website to work properly: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/sys/examples/tutorials/ex2.c.html

Comment: We're assuming it's a problem with the environment, not your program per se. If you ran the hello-world example fine, it might be working, for example, because you ran it out of a common shared directory that was available on all MPI nodes. When I say "node", I'm referring to MPI's view of things: it launches each thread/rank on a "node". Often those nodes are other hosts. In your case, not. Depending on configuration, mpirun might be trying to do a remote shell execution to the localhost. Doing so requires the environment be so that mpirun can run itself, find its libraries and your program.

Comment: It's a mystery to @casey and myself how mpirun will launch your program with exactly 1 node when told to use 4. Either its your "environment", or there is some mysterious problem within Solve. Eliminate the possibility that it is related to your code, by removing `Solve.new` and `ps->getFile` and trying again. If MPI-size is still only size 1, the problem is (almost certainly) your environment.